# Legend order in barplot

Tags: r, plot, legend

I hope you are doing well.

I am using barplot()

```
allvax <- table(data$vaxtype, data$vaxdate)

barplot(allvax,
    ylim = c(0,18000), 
    main = "Vaccination January 2021 to February 2022", xlab = "Mois", ylab = "Patients",
    col = c("red","indianred1","indianred2","indianred3","blue", "cyan", "cyan3","lightcyan1"),
    legend.text = TRUE,
    args.legend = list(x = "topright", bty="n", cex = 0.8, ncol = 2),
    
    )
```

I would like to change the order of the legend for esthetic purpose. How can I change the order changing the order from 8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1 to 1-2-3-4-5-6-7.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given you didn't posted an example data, here is an overall solution:

```
barplot(df)
legend("topright", legend = df[,1])
```

With `df` being your dataframe, and df[,1] being the column you want to base the legend on.

ps: you can alter the colors with the argument `fill` inside `legend()`